# Searching two words in a single line through Notepad++

Tags: search, notepad++

How would I find the lines in Notepad++ where there's a string starting with some words, and has some words in between of the whole string.

For example:

There's a line in code:

1. getSecureURL("XYZ/ABC/Right.jsp", cde);
2. getSecureURL("XYZ/ABC/xyx.jsp", cde);
3. getSecureURL("ABC/ABC/Right.jsp", cde);

Now I want all lines in code containing these words in a single line: *getSecureURL* and *Right.jsp*

in this case, lines 1 & 3.

How to achieve this through Notepad++?

Answer (score 3):

Open the find tool (`ctrl + f`) and check "Regular Expressions" checkbox at the bottom, use the RegExp below and click "Find All in Current Document"

```
getSecureUrl(.*)Right.jsp
```

You can also bookmark all occurences with the Tab `Mark` instead of `Find` and search with `Mark All`

Answer (score 1):

Search with regular expression:
`getSecureURL.*Right[.]jsp`

Answer (score 0):

```
getSecureURL.*Right.jsp
```

For more information, read the Wikipedia article about [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: Posting comments about removing incorrect tags in your question. You could always edit the question instead. :) In this case, I already fixed it.